# Change header background-color in Excel file

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a table which I export to Excel.
How can I change the background-color from my header row while exporting to Excel?

Here is my code:

```
exportExcel() {
    var row = new Array();
    var header;

    //Get header
    this.data.forEach(data => {
      header = Object.keys(data);
    });

    row.push(header);

    //Push data
    this.data.forEach(data => {
      let dataProps = Object.values(data);
      row.push(dataProps);
    });

    const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(row);

    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');


    XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'export.xlsx');
  }
```

Comment: Which library is `XLSX`?

Comment: @HarunYılmaz https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

Comment: As well as I understand from [this link](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/906#issuecomment-390499846), this feature is available only on paid version. Here they tell why: https://gist.github.com/SheetJSDev/24b8acd317d01999d721b38de7c53021